# Open files limit does not work as before in OSX Yosemite

Tags: macos, ulimit, osx-yosemite

I just updated the Mac OS X to Yosemite, and now some applications do not work (IBM DB2). I know that I need to set the Open Files to 65000, however the command does not work.

```
Andress-MBP:~ root# ulimit -n 12288
Andress-MBP:~ root# ulimit -n 12289
-sh: ulimit: open files: cannot modify limit: Invalid argument
```

Why is this happening and how can I correct the problem?

Answer (score 30):

It seems like there is an entirely different method for changing the open files limit for each version of OS X!

**For OS X Sierra** (10.12.X) you need to:

1. In `/Library/LaunchDaemons` create a file named `limit.maxfiles.plist` and paste the following in (feel free to change the two numbers, which are the soft and hard limits, respectively):

   ```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>  
     <!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN"  
             "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
     <plist version="1.0">  
       <dict>
         <key>Label</key>
         <string>limit.maxfiles</string>
         <key>ProgramArguments</key>
         <array>
           <string>launchctl</string>
           <string>limit</string>
           <string>maxfiles</string>
           <string>64000</string>
           <string>524288</string>
         </array>
         <key>RunAtLoad</key>
         <true/>
         <key>ServiceIPC</key>
         <false/>
       </dict>
     </plist>
   ```
2. Change the owner of your new file:

   ```
   sudo chown root:wheel /Library/LaunchDaemons/limit.maxfiles.plist
   ```
3. Load these new settings:

   ```
   sudo launchctl load -w /Library/LaunchDaemons/limit.maxfiles.plist
   ```
4. Finally, check that the limits are correct:

   ```
   launchctl limit maxfiles
   ```

Comment: Looking forward to a new answer for macOS 10.13! :)

Comment: The process did not work for me until I restarted. Thanks! it really helped a lot

Comment: This gist also says modifying these files is the way to update this open file limit for Sierra https://gist.github.com/tombigel/d503800a282fcadbee14b537735d202c

Comment: Restart is necessary for the limits to work (even if step #4 does show the updated values)

Comment: This method also works for macOS 10.15 Catalina.

Answer (score 22):

I see you asked this question all over.

There is a kernel limit you have to deal with, kern.maxfiles  which is the kernel limit and can't be exceeded when setting ulimit.

See the Krypted blog page [Maximum Files in Mac OS X](http://krypted.com/mac-os-x/maximum-files-in-mac-os-x/) for a description on how to manipulate kern.maxifiles using sysctl.

I haven't loaded Yosemite on my Mac yet.  The `sysctl -w kern.maxfiles=65000` works on Mavericks, which has the same kern.maxfiles=12288 limit by default.

I checked on my VM OS X 10.6.8 and it had the same limit which begs the question of how it was previously working prior to your OS X version.

There's a slide share ([DB2 for Mac OS X Installing and setting up DB2 for Mac OS X](http://www.slideshare.net/Tess98/db2-for-mac-os-x-installing-and-setting-up-db2-for-mac-os-x)) showing the recommended limits for using DB2, see **Increase System Parameters** page 7.

> **Increase System Parameters**
>
> Open /etc/sysctl.conf (or create it if it doesn't already exists) and insert the following settings. These settings increase some settings for shared memory and user limits that DB2 needs in order to work on Mac.
>
> Add the following to /etc/sysctl.conf
>   kern.sysv.shmmax=1073741824
>   kern.sysv.shmmin=1
>   kern.sysv.shmmni=4096
>   kern.sysv.shmseg=32
>   kern.sysv.shmall=1179648
>   kern.maxfilesperproc=65536
>   kern.maxfiles=65536

It sounds like you lost your `/etc/sysctl.conf` file when you upgraded.

Comment: Actually, I installed DB2 long time ago and it worked. Then I updated to Maverick last year, without any problem. And today, I updated to Yosemite and this problem appear. I cannot start my already installed DB2.

Comment: Another thing is that my sysctl.conf is identical to the file you put in your post. I created the first time I installed DB2 (one year ago), but I did not touch it for the migration.

Comment: The problem was some blankspaces in that file: https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/forums/html/topic?id=0597855f-0a90-46aa-be02-9fae4e93232f

Comment: Trailing spaces, who would have thought. Apple is supposed to have some of the best programmers in the world.

Comment: @user187561 `sysctl(8)` comes from BSD.

Comment: And it's chock full of Apple changes.

Comment: This saved me!! I am currently running my Mac on El Capitan. Thanks!

Answer (score 13):

In Mac OS 10.10 it seems the ulimit setting can't exceed the launchctl limit setting.

So you should first run *launchctl limit maxfiles* in terminal to get the current setting:

```
launchctl limit maxfiles
maxfiles    256            unlimited
```

So in my case the soft limit is 256, the hard limit is unlimited.
And then if i want to set the soft limit to 512:

```
sudo launchctl limit maxfiles 512 unlimited
```

Detailed usage of launchctl for setting limits can be found here:
https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/launchctl.1.html

Comment: 'launchctl limit maxfiles 512 unlimited'  appears to set my (soft, hard) limits to (512,10240) on Yosemite 10.10.5 on 2015-09-30

Comment: "launchctl limit maxfiles unlimited unlimited ; launchctl limit maxfiles" indicates that 10240 is the largest limit that may be entered.  Using larger numbers silently fails, leaving the setting as before.