# Increase number of open files in mac high sierra

Tags: mac, ulimit, launchctl, macos-highsierra

On a mac high sierra 10.13.3 I have 256 open files.
I want to raise it and I open a terminal and enter

```
sudo launchctl limit maxfiles 1000000 1000000
```

This doesnt change anything when I enter

```
ulimit -a
```

I still get 256

But it does change something, because when I enter

```
sudo launchctl limit maxfiles 1000 1000
```

the system just stops working until a restart.

What is the right way to Increase number of open files in mac high sierra

btw:
Following command changes the open files just for the specific terminal session

```
ulimit -n 4096
```

Comment: Related answer: https://superuser.com/questions/827984/open-files-limit-does-not-work-as-before-in-osx-yosemite/1171026#1171026